# combobox items not displaying but are set

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I am updating my combobox with items, it works fine the first time I open the form but the second, it is setting the values, but they are not getting displayed.

```
combo.Items.Clear();
int selectedIndex = -1;
foreach(var item in itemstoadd)
{
    int index = combo.Items.Add(item.Name + " - " + item.Description);
    if (item.Name.Equals(itemToSelect))
    {
        selectedIndex = index;
    }
}
combo.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex;
```

so after the second time combo.Items has a count of 7 and all values are valid.
but then when the method finishes and the form redraws, the Items list has NOT been updated.

I have looked around stackoverflow and cannot find anything that works for me.

it it on the right thread, there is only 1 instance that i can tell.
I have tried BeginUpdate() / EndUpdate()
Update()
Suspend / ResumeLayout

but still nothing will update this items display.

itemtoSelect is passed into this method, and this is called from another combobox event selectedindexchanged, and initially when i setup the display.

I have hit debug points in the code and the items are all being set on the first window opening and the second window opening.
I think the only think im not 100% sure is if the combobox is the right combobox, as in if its the older one from the first window opening.
I think i can just check this with gethashcode() is there another way to check the reference of an object to confirm if it is the one i think it is?

Comment: Which method "finishes"? You are showing just a small piece of code. In which method this code is? And you have a typo ion the foreach

Comment: you have checked that you get in the foreach after the first time

Comment: I have checked the gethashcode and it is a different code on the combobox i display to the one that my breakpoint fires on and has the correct values, so i think i am editing the old combobox, that is no longer visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had an event i had NOT deallocated, that was keeping the original combobox alive and keeping the event that i had breakpointed firing on the old combobox.

once i deallocated this event on closing of the window, then next time i create the window and the combobox it all works great.

Answer (score 0):

When you clear `Combo.Items` it resets the SelectedIndex. Then, when you make the assignment `combo.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex;`, it generates a new SelectedIndexChanged event, even if you set it to the original value. This can cause problems if you have not completed execution of the first SelectedIndexChanged handler call.

Comment: sorry maybe i didnt explain well but my combobox event listed is called from a different combobox, so this wont happen.